Issue with Environment Variables in Electron Build Using Electron-Vite and Electron-Builder
I am building a Windows app with a React ViteJS project using Electron. The setup involves electron-vite for development and electron-builder for creating the production build. I have three .env files:

.env.development for development mode
.env.production for production
mode
.env.build for the software build process

The development (.env.development) and production (.env.production) environment variables are working correctly. However, when building the application, the variables from .env.build are not being properly picked up in the final build.
Here are the scripts I'm using:
"electron:dev-mock": "concurrently -k \"npm run electron:dev\" \"npm run mock-server\"",
"electron:prod": "electron-vite dev --mode production",
"electron:preview": "electron-vite preview",
"electron:prebuild": "electron-vite build",
"electron:build": "dotenv -e .env.build -- npx electron-vite build && dotenv -e .env.build -- npx electron-builder -w"

electron/main.ts details are below
import { app, shell, BrowserWindow } from "electron";
import { electronApp, optimizer, is } from "@electron-toolkit/utils";
import { join } from "path";

function createWindow(): void {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    show: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: join(__dirname, "../preload/preload.mjs"),
      sandbox: false,
    },
  });

  mainWindow.on("ready-to-show", () => {
    mainWindow.maximize();
    mainWindow.show();
  });

  mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((details) => {
    void shell.openExternal(details.url);
    return { action: "deny" };
  });

  const loadURL = async () => {
    try {
      if (is.dev && process.env["ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL"]) {
        await mainWindow.loadURL(process.env["ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL"]);
      } else {
        await mainWindow.loadFile(join(__dirname, "../renderer/index.html"));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to load URL:", error);
    }
  };

  void loadURL();
}

void app.whenReady().then(() => {
  electronApp.setAppUserModelId("com.canopybiosciences");
  app.on("browser-window-created", (_, window) => {
    optimizer.watchWindowShortcuts(window);
  });

  createWindow();

  app.on("activate", function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
  });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

